# PDO no pinta los errores

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy intentado de indicarle a PDO que cuando se genere un error de sentencia SQL se genere el codigo de error, y actualmente creo que es debido a la conexion:

```
public function __CONSTRUCT() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba;charset=UTF8', 'root', '');
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $this->pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Y por lo que e visto tengo que añadir una línea como esta

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

¿Por lo que mi codigo deberia de quedar de la siguiente manera?

```
public function __CONSTRUCT() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba;charset=UTF8', 'root', '');
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $this->pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception -> ';
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Pero debo de tener algun error por que no lanza nignun tipo de error.

Una de las funciones que utilizo por ejemplo es esta

```
public function Registrar(Categoria $data) {
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO categoria (acronimo,categoria,registro_calidad)
            VALUES (?, ?,?)";
//Ejecucion de la consulta siguiente
        $this->pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array(
            $data->__GET('acronimo'),
            $data->__GET('categoria'),
            $data->__GET('registro_calidad')
                )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

En breve resumen, quiero que pinte el error de SQL que deberia de lanzar.

Comment: creo que deberias usar `PDOException` en vez de `Exception`

Comment: @MiguelOsorio editalo y hazlo como pregunta funciona correctamente tu solución, muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deberás usar `PDOException`en vez de `Exception`